# PL/SQL invalid identifier, table_or_view doesn't exist, column not allowed

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

i'm currently writing a school assignment but got stuck. Unfortunately I have no reference material to browse through and oracle's user manuals are anything but friendly.

The assignment is as followed: "Create a trigger on table sms_budget_abonnement with help of a stored procedure which shows the bill in a new table when a user has passed the max_number of texts to be send within his/hers subscription

these are the relevant tables (<>English translation):

```
KLANTGEGEVENS <customer information>                                

NAAM <name>     GESLACHT    ADRES   WOONPLAATS  MOBIEL_NUMMER   REKENINGNUMMER <billing_number> ABONNEMENTSVORM <subscription type> START_DATUM EIND_DATUM

SMS-BERICHT <text_message>                  

MOBIELE_NUMMER_VERZENDER <mobile_number_sender> MOBIELE_NUMMER_ONTVANGER    LENGTE  DATUM   TIJD    INHOUD (GEDOCEERD)

ABONNEMENTSVORMEN <subscription_type>               

NAAM <subscription_name>    BASISKOSTEN SMS <max_number_of_text_messages>   SMS-BOETE <price per extra message> BELLEN

FACTUUR <billing sheet>

REKENINGNUMMER <billing_number>   DATE  BEDRAG <price> STATUS
```

This is the code/query I have written:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER opdracht_2e
BEFORE INSERT ON SMSBERICHT
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
NR_OF_PERSON NUMBER;
NR_OF_TEXT_MESSAGES NUMBER;
MAX_NUMBER_SMS NUMBER;
REKENING_NUMMER VARCHAR(255);
BOETE NUMBER;

BEGIN
select DISTINCT MOBIELNUMMERVERZENDER INTO NR_OF_PERSON
FROM SMSBERICHT;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO NR_OF_TEXT_MESSAGES
FROM SMSBERICHT
WHERE MOBIELNUMMERVERZENDER = NR_OF_PERSON;

SELECT SMS into MAX_NUMBER_SMS
FROM ABONNEMENTSVORMEN av
JOIN Klantgegevens k ON k.ABBONEMENTSVORM = av.naam
WHERE k.mobielnummmer = NR_OF_PERSON;

SELECT REKENINGNUMMER into REKENING_NUMMER
FROM Klantgegevens
WHERE mobielnummer = NR_OF_PERSON;

SELECT SMS_BOETE INTO BOETE
FROM ABBONEMENTSVORMEN av
JOIN Klantgegevens k on k.ABBONEMENTSVORM = av.naam
WHERE k.mobielnummer = NR_OF_PERSON;

IF(NR_OF_TEXT_MESSAGES > MAX_NUMBER_SMS) THEN
insert into factuur
values (REKENING_NUMMER, SYSDATE, (NR_OF_TEXT_MESSAGES - MAX_NUMBER_SMS) * BOETE, "TE BETALEN");
END IF;
END;
```

However I'm getting the following errors which don't really help me in the right direction, if anyone care's to clarify these messages to me that would be awesome.

```
Project: sqldev.temp:/IdeConnections%23hanze.jpr
hanze
Error(16,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(19,7): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "K"."MOBIELNUMMMER": invalid identifier
Error(25,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(26,6): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Error(31,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(32,84): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `m` in line 19:

```
WHERE k.mobielnummmer = NR_OF_PERSON;
```

The second error is in this section, specifically the `FROM` lone:

```
SELECT SMS_BOETE INTO BOETE
FROM ABBONEMENTSVORMEN av
JOIN Klantgegevens k on k.ABBONEMENTSVORM = av.naam
WHERE k.mobielnummer = NR_OF_PERSON;
```

An earlier reference only has one B; `ABBONEMENTSVORMEN`. So you are using the wrong name. It doesn't help that the table descriptions you showed are not accurate. It would have better to show the actual definitions, e.g. from `describe <table>`.

You have a string value enclosed in double quotes instead of single quotes inthis line:

```
values (REKENING_NUMMER, SYSDATE, (NR_OF_TEXT_MESSAGES - MAX_NUMBER_SMS) * BOETE, "TE BETALEN");
```

It should be `'TE BETALEN'`. Double-quoted or unquoted strings are interpreted as identifiers, in this context a column name.

All pretty simple mistakes that were fairly clearly indicated by the error messages.

Comment: Thanks very much, such eye for detail. It seemed the problem was indeed the syntax . I didn't know about the describe table function. Will keep that in mind. Can you maybe give me a reference to a book, or url which focuses on using oracle pl/sql?